# Get element that doesn't have a specific id - jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is pretty simple ... but I just can't get it to work. This is what I m doing.

```
<li><a href="#" class="myClass" id="idOne">Click1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="myClass" id="idTwo">Click2</a></li>
```

If I click Click1 `pickID` will be `idOne`, but I don't know how to get the idTwo. What s the syntax for getting the id from the element with class `myClass` that doesn't have the id  `pickID` ?

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    var pickID = $(this).attr('id');
    var notPickId = $('myClass').attr(not(pickID));// ??? this is probably so wrong ... I didn't even try it 

});
```

Comment: for choosing by id, `.attr('#idOne')` `.attr('#idTwo')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var notPickId = $('.myClass').not(this).attr('id');
```

or

```
var notPickID = $('.myclass').not('#' + pickID).attr('id');
```

or

```
var notPickId = $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').attr('id');
```

---

[this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

[.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var notPickID = $(".myclass:not(#" + pickID + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
var pickID = $(this).attr('id');
$(".myClass[id!='" + pickID  + "']").attr("id")
```